# How to retrieve user details from graph API using @pnp/js?

Tags: sharepoint-online, crm

I am trying to set up a CRM solution using SharePoint and Office 365, i want to get all the user details from graph api, how do i achieve it using @pnp/js. We were using an [office 365 crm](https://www.mydock365.com/crm) before, which had this specific feature that allowed to view all the users from the solution, so im trying to develop something like that. Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

There is @pnp/graph/users could be used with SPFx solution.

https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/graph/users/

```
import { graph } from "@pnp/graph";
import "@pnp/graph/users";

const matchingUser = await graph.users.getById('jane@contoso.com')();
```

[Configure the API permissions requests](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-aad-tutorial#configure-the-api-permissions-requests)

Install the libraries in SPFx project.

```
npm install @pnp/logging @pnp/common @pnp/odata @pnp/graph --save
```

[SPFx guideline](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview)